# How to wait on sequelize executing a findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got a route using Sequelize.js

```
app.get('/api/users/:username', (req, res) => {
  const foundUser = getUserByUsername(req.params.username);
  console.log(`foundUser = ${foundUser}`);
  return res.send(foundUser);
});
```

the getUserByUsername function is as follows

```
const getUserByUsername = username => {
  Viewer.findOne({
    where: {username}
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.dataValues);//the object with the data I need
    return response.dataValues;
  });
};
```

I hoped on getting the object in my const foundUser in my route, but it seems I need to wait until the findOne has been executed, because in my console I can see that the log of foundUser (which is undefined then) is executed before the function getUserByUsername

```
foundUser = undefined
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `instakluiten`, `role`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `viewers` AS `viewer` WHERE `viewer`.`username` = 'instak' LIMIT 1;
{ id: 19,
  username: 'instak',
  instakluiten: 18550,
  role: 'moderators',
  createdAt: 2016-10-02T16:27:44.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2016-10-09T10:17:40.000Z }
```

How can I make sure that my foundUser will be updated with the data áfter the user has been found?

Comment: You can't return result like this, you need to write your code in callback after that you will get it

Comment: use callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **return** the promise that Sequelize creates and then wait for it to resolve. So the `getUserByUsername` becomes:

```
const getUserByUsername = username => {
  return Viewer.findOne({
    where: {username}
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.dataValues);//the object with the data I need
    return response.dataValues;
  });
};
```

and in the route:

```
app.get('/api/users/:username', (req, res) => {
  getUserByUsername(req.params.username).then(foundUser => {
    res.send(foundUser);
  });
});
```

This is because you need to keep the chain of promises. If you forget to return it, the function returns `undefined` end even if the promise is finallly resolved, the value it resolves to never gets up back in the chain.

Comment: That doesn't work, the then (after getUserByUsername) throws a TypeError

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Did you return the promise, as I wrote above? According to the Sequelize docs and my own experience, `Model.findOne()` returns a promise, so as `then()`, so if you get `undefined` it sounds like you didn't return it.

Comment: I had actually copied your code and put mine in comments, I tried the same again right now and it doés work... How is this able to work though? You return response.dataValues, that's not a promise... Or is it? I mean, could you explain why I can call .then on getUserByUsername?

Comment: I'll add some explanation inside the answer, as I'm not sure if 600 characters in the comments are enough

Comment: Well, I thought to myself that I'm probably not going to explain it better as it is already explained in various resources over the Internet... But the key concept here is something called promise chain and the fact that by *returning* a promise (look at the getUserByUsername function in my example) you can access the values that were created by promises inside this promise. See "Rookie mistake #5" here: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/api/users/:username', (req, res) => {
getUserByUsername(req.params.username, function(err, result){
const foundUser = result;
console.log(`foundUser = ${foundUser}`);
 res.send(foundUser); 
});

});



const getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
Viewer.findOne({
where: {username}
}).then(response => {
console.log(response.dataValues);//the object with the data I need
return callback(null, response.dataValues);
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid it with promise or with callback

```
app.get('/api/users/:username', (req, res) => {
  getUserByUsername(req.params.username, function(err, foundUser) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(`foundUser = ${foundUser}`);
      return res.send(foundUser);
    } else {
      res.send(err)
    }
  });
});



const getUserByUsername = (username, callback) => {
  Viewer.findOne({
    where: {
      username
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.dataValues); //the object with the data I need
    return callback(null, response.dataValues);
  });
};
```